# コントローラからテンプレート（ビュー）にデータを渡すときにMapを使う形式はどのようなものですか？

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[Model, ModelMap and ModelView in Spring MVC | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view)

を見ると

コントローラからテンプレート（ビュー）にデータを渡す方法として、

- `Model`
- `ModelMap`
- `ModelAndView`

とあるようです。

しかし
[spring-petclinic/OwnerController.java at master · spring-projects/spring-petclinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/owner/OwnerController.java#L59)
を見ると

```
@GetMapping("/owners/new")
public String initCreationForm(Map<String, Object> model) {
  Owner owner = new Owner();
  model.put("owner", owner);
  return VIEWS_OWNER_CREATE_OR_UPDATE_FORM;
}
```

や

```
@GetMapping("/owners/find")
public String initFindForm(Map<String, Object> model) {
  model.put("owner", new Owner());
  return "owners/findOwners";
}
```

というように `Map<String, Object>` を使っています。この `Map` を使った形式はどのようなものでしょうか？

もしかして、`Model`, `ModelMap`, `ModelAndView` のどれかが、 `Map`形式のエイリアスだったりしますか？

---

[spring-petclinic/PetController.java at master · spring-projects/spring-petclinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/owner/PetController.java#L69)

では

```
public String initCreationForm(Owner owner, ModelMap model) {
    Pet pet = new Pet();
    owner.addPet(pet);
    model.put("pet", pet);
    return VIEWS_PETS_CREATE_OR_UPDATE_FORM;
}
```

`ModelMap`が使われているので、なにか意図的に使い分けされているような気もしています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> もしかして、Model, ModelMap, ModelAndView のどれかが、 Map形式のエイリアスだったりしますか？

いいえ。

Springのドキュメントには、`Model`、`ModelMap`、`ModelAndView`、`Map`の他にも様々な型がパラメーターや戻り値に利用できることが書いてあります。

1.3.3. Handler Methods
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods